# Fetching values from previous rows only if it is different from the current row [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

[image: requirement image]

This is a part of a table for a single patient where we have some patients and their current Rx fill dates, drug_names and some other stuff. So basically, you see this column 'Prev_Other_Drug_Date', which contains the dates of the last prescribed drug which is different from the current drug. So for the first 3 rows, it is null, because the drug_names are the same "AKSTRIA". For Row_Num 5 we have the date of the last drug which is different from the previous drug.

I don't understand how I should proceed to achieve this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO!, The question editor gives you the tools to "draw" your table. Please use it instead of linking an image.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query, and please don't post pictures of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach this as a gaps-and-islands problem. Here is a solution using window functions:

```
select t.*,
    max(lag_fill_dt) over(partition by patient_id, grp) as prev_other_drug_date
from (
    select t.*,
        count(lag_fill_dt) over(partition by patient_id order by fill_dt) as grp
    from (
        select t.*, 
            case when drug_name <> lag(drug_name) over(partition by patient_id order by fill_dt)
                then lag(fill_dt) over(partition by patient_id order by fill_dt) 
            end as lag_fill_dt
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
```

The idea is to compare the drug name on the current with the previous row of the same patient; if they differ, then we retain the previous date. We can then use another level of nesting to bring the latest non-null date per group.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was perfect and absolutely what I wanted.

Comment: Done man. Thanks again. Basically, I'm a bit new to Window functions, would be needing a lot of help in subsequent time. Also it was my first question on stackoverflow. Good to see such help and support. Cheers man! Have a great day!